# Sound is not working with Kazam when I use my microphone

Tags: microphone, kazam

The sound is disactivated with Kazam. I don't know how to reverse the steam.

With the following command line `pactl list | grep -A2 'Source #'`, it is indicated that

> Source #5
>         State: SUSPENDED
>         Name: alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.analog-mono

How can I activate the sound from kazam using a microphone?